# Android Studio 3.2 - Problem loading widget

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I'm developing a home screen widget and I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.2 and all my dependencies today. Now, when I uninstall the app and I reinstall it, in my widget appears "Problem loading widget", without any way to fix it.

I googled a bit in the Android Issue Tracker and I found out that someone reported my exact same bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117266820

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?
Can this bug impact the app installed by the play store?

Comment: same here. its happening to me too. ;-;